# Error al compilar archivos parciales con sass

Tags: sass, scss

Buenas colegas estoy teniendo un problema con el prompt de Ruby al trabajar con sass estoy trabando con archivos parciales mediante el **@import aqui-lo-importado**

Nunca me habia pasado busque en Google pero no encontré la respuesta que busco

```
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
      error styles.scss (Line 2: Invalid CSS after "@import ": expected file to
import (string or url()), was "generales")
```

**Se importa así**

```
@import generales
@import header
@import main
@import footer
@import responsive
```

Comment: puedes mostrar tu linea de código como haces el @import ? !!

Comment: Si así los hago img: http://prntscr.com/hv6mj4

Comment: Te falta ponerle las comillas ejemplo @import "variables";

Comment: listo revise y el error era por parte la declaración del archivo  muchas gracias :D

Comment: esta bien mucho mejor que hallas logrado.

Comment: Soy nuevo como te doy puntiación me parecio muy buena y acertada tu ayuda ;)

Comment: pues dale la flecha arriba a un comentario míos así lo tomara como útil.